# gnu cflow - not recognizing "typedef struct"

Tags: c, call-graph, cflow

[GNU `cflow`](https://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/) analyzes a collection of C source files and prints a graph, charting control flow within the program.

My `.c` or `.cpp` file

```
typedef struct _type_1{
    int a;
} type_1_t;


typedef struct _type_2{
    int a;
} type_2_t;

int main()
{
    type_1_t t1;
    type_2_t t2;

    t1.a = 55;
    t2.a = 99;

    return 0;
}
```

The command is `cflow.exe test.c -i s -i x > test.graph 2>&1` and the output is:

```
cflow.exe:test.c:7: a redefined
cflow.exe:test.c:2: this is the place of previous definition
main() <int main () at test.c:11>:
    type_1_t <type_1_t at test.c:3>
    t1
    type_2_t <type_2_t at test.c:8>
    t2
```

**QUESTION**

Why does it say "**a redefined**"?
It can only be because it doesn't recognize the `typedef struct` construct so how do I fix it?

**UPDATE**

I ran `cflow` again with `--debug=1` and it gave me this:

```
test.c:3: type _type_1
test.c:3: a/-1 defined to int a
test.c:3: type_1_t/-1 defined to type_1_t
test.c:8: type _type_2
cflow.exe:test.c:7: a redefined
cflow.exe:test.c:2: this is the place of previous definition
main() <int main () at test.c:15>:
    type_1_t <type_1_t at test.c:3>
    t1
    type_2_t <type_2_t at test.c:8>
    t2
    f1() <int f1 () at test.c:10>
test.c:8: a/-1 defined to int a
test.c:8: type_2_t/-1 defined to type_2_t
test.c:11: f1/0 defined to int f1 ()
test.c:16: main/0 defined to int main ()
```

Just as we suspected: it's not treating each struct . . . as a struct i.e. the ability to have the exact same identifier in two different structs.

So how to fix this? I'm emailing `cflow` mailing list. Hopefully will hear back soon. Until then, I'm going to play around with the [syntactic classes](https://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/manual/html_node/Syntactic-classes.html#Syntactic-classes) and see if I can't trigger the correct behavior.

I'll post my own answer if I get an answer back from mailing list.

Comment: @4386427 I know the reason why `cflow` thinks it's being redefined: it doesn't understand the `typedef struct` construct.

Comment: I think you're jumping to conclusions. I don't know why `cflow` is saying that `a` is redefined, but it's unlikely that a tool in widespread use would fail to understand a feature that's been in standard C for decades. I don't get that error using cflow 1.4 on Ubuntu. What does `cflow --version` print?

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm using `cflow` 1.5 on windows. I'll try it with 1.4. Also, in Linux, the [configuration values are read from an environment variable and .cflowrc](https://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/manual/cflow.html#Configuration). So, yours may be loading in some config options that tell `cflow` how to parse the `typedef struct`. I'll build 1.4 and get back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clearly a bug in `cflow`.

I just built `cflow` versions 1.3, 1.4, and 1.5 on my system (Ubuntu 17.04). Versions 1.3 and 1.4 do not exhibit the problem you describe. Version 1.5 does.

Here's a simpler test case that exhibits the problem:

```
$ cat c.c
typedef struct type1 { int a; } type1;
typedef struct type2 { int a; } type2;
$ cflow --version | head -n 1
cflow (GNU cflow) 1.5
$ cflow c.c
cflow:c.c:2: a redefined
cflow:c.c:1: this is the place of previous definition
$
```

(`typedef struct` and separate namespaces for different structure types have been features of C for about three decades. It's not plausible that `cflow` would fail to support them -- and in fact earlier versions handle them with no problem.)

As a workaround, use `cflow` 1.4. I also suggest submitting a bug report. It doesn't appear that this one has been reported. (The OP has now [reported it](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-cflow/2017-12/msg00003.html) to the `bug-cflow@gnu.org` mailing list and received an [acknowledgement](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-cflow/2017-12/msg00005.html).)

Comment: If you like, I can submit a bug report myself.

Comment: I just did it. Unfortunately, version `1.4` doesn't output symbols when using `-i x` but it's preferable to the other behavior.

Comment: @Adrian: I don't see it on the [Bugzilla page](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=cflow).

Comment: I sent it at 3:38PM EST title `Bug 1.5: typedef struct doesn't result in separate namespace` to `bug-cflow@gnu.org`. It's the same address as for the mailing list for help so it's moderated.

Comment: I just got an email from the guy saying "thanks for reporting it"

Comment: @Adrian: I don't know how that project manages bugs internally. As long as they've been informed, whether via a Bugzilla ticket or an e-mail to the appropriate list, I'm not inclined to worry about it. I've added links to your report and the acknowledgement.